# How to define foreach loop with related array?

Tags: arrays, loops, templates, foreach, dwoo

[image]

```
<{foreach item=_loop from=$_project}>
<{if $_loop[title] as $_loop[items]}><{$_loop[title]}><{/if}>
<{/foreach}>
```

I sorry that I newly work with dwoo template but dwoo project is dead, I know this wrong syntax applied but i would like example below.

If for each loop like this example.

- If the items title is **Apple**, the project title will be **Restaurant**.
- If the items title is **Premium Guest**, the project title will be **Hotel**.

Comment: Anyone can help?